# Missing { inserted: but no parenthesis is missing

Tags: math-mode, errors, underscore, missing

Good evening everybody,

I already searched for this problem but didn't find a solution. When compiling my LaTeX file, the error "Missing { inserted" appears but everything seems to be ok with the equation I've written.

```
u_i\left(x_i,t\right)=\overline{u_i}\left(x_i\right)+u^'_i\left(x_i,t\right)={{\mathop{\mathrm{lim}}_{T\to \ \infty } \ \ }\frac{1}{T} \int^T_0{u_i\left(x_i,t\right)dt}\ }+u^'_i\left(x_i,t\right)
```

The result should be as that in the image.
Anybody has some ideas on how to solve the problem?

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Simplify your code using `\lim`

Comment: You cannot have `^'`, ust `'` will do.

Comment: Simplified code: `\[ u_i\left(x_i,t\right) = \overline{u_i} \left(x_i\right)+u'_i\left(x_i,t\right)=\lim_{T\to \infty} \frac{1}{T} \int^T_0 u_i\left(x_i,t\right)dt +u'_i\left(x_i,t\right) \]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by Sigur, your `lim` was unnecessarily weird, but the error comes from `^'`, which is a double superscript. This works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[u_i\left(x_i,t\right)=\overline{u_i}\left(x_i\right)
+u'_i\left(x_i,t\right)=\lim_{T\to \ \infty }
\frac{1}{T} \int^T_0u_i\left(x_i,t\right)\mathrm{d}t+u'_i\left(x_i,t\right) \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

You seem to like a space before `\infty`. so I kept it, personally I'd not do that.

Comment: wow that was embarrassingly easy! Thank you, I was freaking out but it was as simple as that!

Answer (score 4):

The error message shows the exact point of the error

```
l.6 ...T} \int^T_0{u_i\left(x_i,t\right)dt}\ }+u^'
                                                  _i\left(x_i,t\right)
```

`'` is  superscript autmatically so this should just be `u'`

Note that `{\mathop{\mathrm{lim}}` the `\mathop` is doing nothing as the `{}` around the ouside force it to be a `\mathord`. You just need `\lim` here. Also You should almost never need `\` in math mode as that is the inter-word space from the text font.